# How do I setTimeout on an inline onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

Basically I have this bit of HTML:

```
<a class="button animated none" 
onclick="document.getElementById('local').scrollIntoView();" href=...
```

And I want to add a setTimeout to the bit of javascript in it. Have tried several ways, but everything seems to return an 'undefined' error.

Edit: What I've tried:

```
setTimeout (document.getElementById('local').scrollIntoView(), 2000);
document.getElementById('local').setTimeout (scrollIntoView(), 2000);
document.getElementById('local').scrollIntoView(); setTimeout (scrollIntoView(), 2000);
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: setTimeout (document.getElementById('local').scrollIntoView(), 2000);

document.getElementById('local').setTimeout (scrollIntoView(), 2000);

document.getElementById('local').scrollIntoView(); setTimeout (scrollIntoView(), 2000);

Comment: `setTimeout` accepts a function reference. You didn't do that in every attempts you made. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code (specifically the `scrollIntoView()` function), it seems to me that you should be calling `scrollIntoView()` and passing the element (`local`) that you want to display (e.g. - `setTimeout("scrollIntoView('local')", 2000);`)

Comment: @SenorAmor - Is that `eval` I just saw in your comment? [Don't do that please.](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - I don't see "eval" anywhere. ;)

Comment: @SenorAmor The String in `setTimeout` is basically an `eval`.

Comment: I know that, hence the winky face. :)

Comment: It was also why I commented instead of answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of `setTimeout` is a function, but you're sending the result of executing `scrollIntoView()`, which is probably `undefined`. Try wrapping the call in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  document.getElementById('local').scrollIntoView() 
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Or with arrow style:
setTimeout(() => { 
  document.getElementById('local').scrollIntoView() 
}, 2000);